# Interromper execução de uma função javascript, dentro do jQuery each?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Preciso interromper a execução do `.each` quando uma opção não for atendida, estou usando `return false;`, porém o código após o bloco `each` continua sendo executado. Segue o exemplo do código:

```js
function Salvar(element){
      //$(element).parent().parent().children("td:nth-child(1)").css({"color": "red", "border": "2px solid red"});
      var par = $(element).parent().parent();
      var date = par.children("td:nth-child(1)").children().val();
      par.children().each(function(i){
          if(par.children("td:nth-child("+i+")").children().val() == ''){
            par.children("td:nth-child("+i+")").children().addClass('error').focus();
            return false;
          }else{
            $('#tbl-metas tbody tr td input').removeClass('error');
          }
      });
        
        var data      =   par.children("td:nth-child(1)").children().val();
        var va     =   par.children("td:nth-child(2)").children().val();
        var vb  =   par.children("td:nth-child(3)").children().val();
        var vc       =   par.children("td:nth-child(4)").children().val();

        console.log('data: '+data+' va: '+va+' vb: '+vb+' vc: '+vc);
  }
```

```css
.error{
  color: red; 
  border: 2px solid red;
  }
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class="table" id="tbl-metas">
        <caption>Cadastro de metas</caption>
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>Mês</th>
                    <th>Venda 1</th>
                    <th>Venda 2</th>
                    <th>Venda 3</th>
                    <th>Ajuste</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td><input type="date" name="month" value="<?= date('Y-m').'-01' ?>"  style="width:100%"></td>
                    <td><input type="text" class="money" name="txtVendaA" id="txtVendaA" style="width:100%"></td>
                    <td><input type="text" class="money" name="txtVendaB" id="txtVendaB" style="width:100%"></td>
                    <td><input type="text" class="money" name="txtVendaC" id="txtVendaC" style="width:100%"></td>
                    <td><button class="btn btn-success btn-sm" id="btnSave" name="btnSave" onclick="Salvar(this)">Salvar</button></td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
```

Comment: E por que não faz um `for` normal que é muito mais simples?

Comment: E performático. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Como sugerido nos comentários pelo [Maniero](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/users/101/maniero), o mais ideal é você usar o laço [`for`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for). Algo mais ou menos assim:

```js
function getEl() {
  var $els = $('ul > li');
  
  for (var i = 0; i < $els.length; i++) {
    var text = $($els[i]).text();
    
    if (text === '2') {
      // O valor a seguir será retornado pela função "getEl":
      return text
    }
  }
}

console.log(getEl());
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<ul>
  <li>1</li>
  <li>2</li>
  <li>3</li>
</ul>
```

No entanto, se você realmente quiser usar o [`jQuery.each`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.each/) (*não recomendo*), você pode fazer algo assim:

```js
function getEl() {
  var $els = $('ul > li');
  
  // Crie um valor logo antes de iniciar as iterações:
  var returnValue = undefined;
  
  $els.each(function() {
    var text = $(this).text();
    
    if (text === '2') {
      // Atribuímos o valor que queremos que a função retorne à variável "returnValue" e, em seguida, interrompemos o loop:
      returnValue = text;
      return false;
    }
  });
  
  // Verifique se o valor de "returnValue" foi alterado. Se sim, retorne o valor.
  if (typeof returnValue !== 'undefined') {
    return returnValue
  }
}

console.log(getEl());
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<ul>
  <li>1</li>
  <li>2</li>
  <li>3</li>
</ul>
```

---

Em suma, as duas soluções são válidas. Mas, para confessar, o uso do [`jQuery.each`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.each/) ou [`.each`](https://api.jquery.com/each/) é extremamente desnecessário, já que o JavaScript por si só já possui várias maneiras de criar loops. Alguns exemplos são:

- [Laço `for`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for);
- [Laço `while`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/while);
- [`Array.prototype.forEach`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach).

Comment: Resolvido utilizando o for, é um problema do jquery continuar a execução mesmo utilizando o `return false;`? vou continuar procurando para entender o funcionamento, muito obrigado.

Answer (score 0):

```
function Salvar(element){
      //$(element).parent().parent().children("td:nth-child(1)").css({"color": "red", "border": "2px solid red"});
      var par = $(element).parent().parent();
      var date = par.children("td:nth-child(1)").children().val();
      par.children().each(function(i){
          if(par.children("td:nth-child("+i+")").children().val() == ''){
            par.children("td:nth-child("+i+")").children().css({"color": "red", "border": "2px solid red"}).focus();
            break;
          }            
      });
        var data      =   par.children("td:nth-child(1)").children().val();
        var va     =   par.children("td:nth-child(2)").children().val();
        var vb  =   par.children("td:nth-child(3)").children().val();
        var vc       =   par.children("td:nth-child(4)").children().val();

        console.log('data: '+data+' va: '+va+' vb: '+vb+' vc: '+vc);
  }
```

Tente substituir o return false por break conforme código acima.

Comment: Já fiz, fica na mesma, obrigado.